# Checking wether or not select box option value contains a match

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How do I go about checking wether or not select box option value contains a match of '08C' and alert(true) if it does.

An example or answer to work from would be appreciated. Sorry in advance for the lack of coding skills as this is beyond my train of thought.

An answer using jQuery is acceptable as well.

```
<select id="fin-code-lobj">
    <optgroup label="08C - Travel for Training">
        <option value="08C1">08C1 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Mandatory (for/by TC employees)</option>
        <option value="08C2">08C2 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Non-Mandatory</option>
        <option value="08C3">08C3 - Travel for Developmental Training</option>
        <option value="08C4">08C4 - Travel for Developmental Language Training</option>
        <option value="08C5">08C5 - Travel for Statutory Language Training</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, just looking that HTML code I can tell you that the whole set of options match with 08C even their values. :-)

Comment: Step 1: Make an effort. Step 2: Then ask us if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#fin-code-lobj").on("change", function(){
  if($(this).find("option:selected").val().indexOf("08C") > -1)){
    alert(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not answers the exact question. There's no mention of a `"change"` Event action going on, rather only *if a select's options value matches "08c"* regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting the `options` in jquery using `$("#fin-code-lobj option")` and then check it like this

```js
$("#fin-code-lobj option").each(function() {
  $(this).val().indexOf("08C") != -1 ? console.log($(this).val() + "- true"): console.log($(this).val() + "- false");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fin-code-lobj">
    <optgroup label="08C - Travel for Training">
        <option value="08C1">08C1 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Mandatory (for/by TC employees)</option>
        <option value="08C2">08C2 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Non-Mandatory</option>
        <option value="08C3">08C3 - Travel for Developmental Training</option>
        <option value="08C4">08C4 - Travel for Developmental Language Training</option>
        <option value="08C5">08C5 - Travel for Statutory Language Training</option>
        <option value="11">Dummy</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert true if:

- there's many select elements...
- at lease one of them has an option which value starts with `08c` (case insensitive)

```js
const matchOptionVal = ( options, str ) => alert (
  [...options].some(op => new RegExp("^"+str, "i").test(str) )
);

[...document.querySelectorAll("select")].forEach(sel => 
  matchOptionVal(sel.options, "08c")
);
```

```html
<select id="fin-code-lobj">
    <optgroup label="08C - Travel for Training">
        <option value="08C1">08C1 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Mandatory (for/by TC employees)</option>
        <option value="08C2">08C2 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Non-Mandatory</option>
        <option value="08C3">08C3 - Travel for Developmental Training</option>
        <option value="08C4">08C4 - Travel for Developmental Language Training</option>
        <option value="08C5">08C5 - Travel for Statutory Language Training</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
Here is a solution that will loop thru each value trying to locate the string you want. Written in pure JS so that there is no libraries or framework dependencies.

```js
function funStart(){
  var objDropDown = document.querySelector("#fin-code-lobj");
  if (typeof(objDropDown)=="undefined"){
    console.log("Dropdown not located");
    return;
  }
  for (a = 1; a <= objDropDown.length; a++){
    if (objDropDown[a-1].value == "08C3"){
      alert("I found 08C5");
      console.log ("Found and alerted" + a);
    }
  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funStart, false);
```

```html
<select id="fin-code-lobj">
    <optgroup label="08C - Travel for Training">
        <option value="08C1">08C1 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Mandatory (for/by TC employees)</option>
        <option value="08C2">08C2 - Travel for Technical/Operational Training – Non-Mandatory</option>
        <option value="08C3">08C3 - Travel for Developmental Training</option>
        <option value="08C4">08C4 - Travel for Developmental Language Training</option>
        <option value="08C5">08C5 - Travel for Statutory Language Training</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```